# Does $¬∀x∀y K(x,y)$ mean the same thing as $¬(∃∃(, ))$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

Does $¬∀x∀y K(x,y)$ mean the same thing as $¬(∃∃(, ))$

Someone is telling me these mean the same thing, but according to De morgan's law, they don't. Because it would become (∀∀¬(, )) which is different.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I agree with you.  That is:

$¬∀x∀y K(x,y)$ means the same thing as $\{~ ∃∃ ~[¬(, )] ~\}.$

Comment: great, so the other guy is wrong then? I just want to clarify this.

Comment: @JohnnyRobertson absolutely, the other guy is wrong.

Comment: Thanks I won 10 bucks.